# django queryet to print product and it's models

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

my models are

```
   class Product(models.Model):

         name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
         desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)

         def __unicode__(self):
                 return self.name

   class ProductModels(models.Model):
          product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
          name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
          price = IntegerField(max_length=50)

          def __unicode__(self):
                 return self.name
```

i can easily print in python , product and it's releated models , but in django template , i am unable to figure out how to print them .

I want data to be seen in html pages like this :

```
    product1    modelpm1
                modelpm2

    product2    modelpm3
                modelpm4
                modelpm5
                          and so on .....
```

Of course I have created table and all the html related tags properly, but I am unable to figure out how to print this way in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same in the template:

```
<ul>
{% for product in objects %}
    <li>{{ product }}
        <ul>
    {% for product_model in product.productmodel_set.all %}
       <li>{{ product_model }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Use the following view:

```
def product_list(request):
   return render(request, 'template.html', {'objects': Product.objects.all()})
```

Or, if you prefer, use the generic views:

```
class ProductList(ListView):
    template = 'template.html'
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
```